# Kernel problem on TOSHIBA

Tags: grub2, kernel, toshiba

I have a SAMSUNG with following specs

- Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
- 8 GB internal memory
- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Since quite some time now, my list of kernels starts with the version 3.13.0.39. With this version I do not have WIFI connection, graphics is not good (and an external monitor is not recognised), and so using this kernel, the system in NOT usable. The next (older) kernel is 3.13.0-37 and the system works with this kernel without any major problem.

My question is twofold:

- why is the system not working with the newest kernel and how should I proceed (without Internet connection) to get this kernel working?
- if the newest kernel cannot be used, how do I have to adapt the GRUB list so that the kernel 3.13.0-37 is the one selected by default.

Tx for your help
Alain

Answer (score 0):

You should look in `/var/log/apt/history.log` or older `/var/log/apt/history.log.*.gz` files if there were any issues during installing the kernel images and compiling initrd.

Also it seems like 3.13.0-44 is currently the latest available in 14.04, so try to install the latest currently available kernel, check history.log for error and try to boot that.

If your find error messages, please edit your question and add them.

---

The command to update or recompile an initrd image is [update-initramfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-initramfs.8.html).